# JavaFX 2 TextArea that changes height depending on its contents

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

In JavaFX 2.2, is there any way to make TextArea (with setWrapText(true) and constant maxWidth) change its height depending on contents?

The desired behaviour: while user is typing something inside the TextArea it resizes when another line is needed and decreases when the line is needed no more.

Or is there a better JavaFX control that could be used in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure the size of the TextArea increases and decreases instead of a `ScrollBar` showing up?

Comment: ScrollBar shows up. ;] And I want it to increase and deacrease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the `prefHeight` of the text area to the height of the text it contains. This is a bit of a hack, because you need a `lookup` to get the text contained in the text area, but it seems to work. You need to ensure that you lookup the `text` node after CSS has been applied. (Typically this means after it has appeared on the screen...)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResizingTextArea extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        textArea.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> obs, Scene oldScene, Scene newScene) {
                if (newScene != null) {
                    textArea.applyCSS();
                    Node text = textArea.lookup(".text");
                    textArea.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>() {
                        @Override
                        public Double call() {
                            return 2+text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
                        }
                    }), text.boundsInLocalProperty()));
                }
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is pretty hacky. I am writing a piece of UI that is used in different places throughout the application, often as a part of a bigger UI graph, that is not always attached to root and visible. Your method relies on guessing the UI state and guessing the binding moment and is therefore a no-go I am afraid. Still, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Updated to (maybe) make it a bit more flexible (more hacky too, though...?). Also took out lambdas since you tagged this javafx-2.

Comment: As there seems to be no more activity on the question I will accept your answer. It is a clever one and what is more important - it works. But honestly, I hope that somebody would post a cleaner one in the future...

Answer (score 3):

Two things to add to James_D's answer (because I lack the rep to comment):

1) For big fonts like size 36+, the text area size was wrong at first but corrected itself when I clicked inside the text area.  You can call `textArea.layout()` after applying CSS, but the text area still does not resize immediately after the window is maximized.  To get around this, call `textArea.requestLayout()` asynchronously in a Change Listener after any change to the `Text` object's local bounds. See below.

2) The text area was still a few pixels short and the scroll bar still visible. If you replace the `2` with `textArea.getFont().getSize()` in the binding, the height fits perfectly to the text, no matter whether the font size is tiny or huge.

```
class CustomTextArea extends TextArea {
    CustomTextArea() {
        setWrapText(true);
        setFont(Font.font("Arial Black", 72));

        sceneProperty().addListener((observableNewScene, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene != null) {
                applyCss();
                Node text = lookup(".text");

                // 2)
                prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
                    return getFont().getSize() + text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
                }, text.boundsInLocalProperty()));

                // 1)                   
                text.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener((observableBoundsAfter, boundsBefore, boundsAfter) -> {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> requestLayout());
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(The above compiles for Java 8. For Java 7, replace the listener lambdas with Change Listeners according to the JavaFX API, and replace the empty `()->` lambdas with `Runnable`.)