# Listener works but Binding doesn't

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Background:

According to the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217429/javafx-2-textarea-that-changes-height-depending-on-its-contents), a `TextArea` has an underlying `Text` node that contains the text and acts as its bounding box.  It is useful for calculating the visual (pre-transform) height of the text, even when the text wraps around.

The `Text` node is not exposed in the public JavaFX 8 API, but it can be gotten via `.lookup()`.  Moreover, it seems it is not initialized till after the `Scene` is rendered. The above said answer shows how to get it successfully by listening to the `Scene`.

Problem:

I have taken the logic of the listener, which works, and implemented it as a binding instead.  But the binding does not work, and I cannot understand why.  The value of the property updated by the listener is successfully set to the new `Text` node, while the value of the binding is always null because it is not detecting the change of `Scene` from null to a `Scene` object.

```
public ObjectExpression<Text> getObservableTextNode(TextArea textArea) {
    // The underlying text node can be looked up only after applying CSS when there is a scene.
    // For that reason we return it as an observable.

    // Way #1: Listener
    ObjectProperty<Text> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    textArea.sceneProperty().addListener((observableNewScene, oldScene, newScene) -> {
        if (newScene != null) {
            textArea.applyCss();
            Node text = textArea.lookup(".text");
            property.set((Text) text);
        } else {
            property.set(null);
        }
    });
    return property;

    // Way #2: Binding - does not update
    ObjectBinding<Text> ob = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        if (textArea.sceneProperty().get() != null) {
            textArea.applyCss();
            return (Text) textArea.lookup(".text");
        }
        return null;
    }, textArea.sceneProperty());
    return ob;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the logics of the listener and binding are the same.  Why then is there a difference?

Comment: This looks like a pretty ugly solution.  You might want to describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish (and why).  There may be a cleaner solution to your problem.  This may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am generating an observable of the Text node, so that I can pass it to another class that will use it. I can achieve my goal by the listener, but that's not relevant. My interest here is in discovering specifically why the binding does not work.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13015698/2991525 This may solve the problem without a workaround.

Comment: Both ways work the same for me. If you really want to do it this way, can you post a [MCVE]?